# How to display non-public image returned by ASP.NET Core with React Native?

Tags: reactjs, image, react-native, asp.net-core, expo

I am setting up a project with three parts: a React web app, a **React-Native mobile app**, and a common **ASP.NET Core backend**. Every part of this is a first for me, this is my first dev job.

The core of the project is about private photos that are taken from the mobile app, sent to the backend, and later sent back to both apps to be displayed in a photo-library fashion.

This question is about the last part: getting the jpeg file from the backend to the **mobile** app and actually displaying it.

In the first stages of development, the app was displaying pictures via a simple url to their exact location. Everyone could type the url and see the picture so it was not private.

Then I tried to actually ask my backend through a controller to send back the picture this way:

```cs
var image = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path);
return File(image, "image/jpeg");
```

This worked great on the React website. But when given the controller url just like the website, React-Native `<Image />` component did not display anything.

Then, only for the mobile app, I sent back from the controller the picture in a Base64 format:

```cs
var image = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
return "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(image);
```

This technically worked but was a lot heavier on the app performance, calls to my backend and the image display in itself both take quite some time.

I feel like this problem is really because of my inexperience, I probably take it the wrong way from the start.

**Is there another way I could send or display private pictures like this ?**

Thanks a lot for your time.